# How do I write selected jQuery DOM elements back out as XHTML snippets?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

I'm wanting to select some DOM elements using jQuery, modify some attributes, and then write the DOM elements back out as xhtml snippets for post processing.  I want the resulting xHTML to have only the attributes specified in the original page html plus the modifications I make with jQuery.

Is there an existing javascript library or API that can help me accomplish this task?

Comment: Does "write out as snippets" mean "store the element's HTML to a string", or something else?

Comment: Also, what does "post processing" mean? Are you wanting do an HTTP POST to a server and store them in a database or something?

Comment: @Matchu "Write out as snippets" does mean store the element's HTML to a string.

Comment: @jessegavin post processing means that I'm going to process the saved x-html on the server.  (My background is middleware and backend systems, thus the terminology mismatch...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The outerHTML jQuery plugin](http://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-outerhtml) gives jQuery support for what I think you're asking for - getting the full HTML for a given tag.

But watch out - you can't trust your user input on this. Any user can easily hijack the data you're going to send for "post-processing" and make it say whatever they want.

Comment: That worked great!  And thanks for the warning about the possible rewrite attacks.